# Google Bigquery does not support _TABLE_SUFFIX now?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a script that selects fields from multiple tables, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  field_1,
  field_2,
  field_3
FROM `auth-api.xxx_yyy.actions*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX > '20180101'
```

Every day we'll have a new table added to our project, the name will be like: `auth-api.xxx_yyy.actions20180105`

Now the query returns an internal error. I tried this, but does not work:

```
SELECT
  field_1,
  field_2,
  field_3
FROM `auth-api.xxx_yyy.actions2018*`
```

I tried out to select just one table, it works just fine so my tables and the field names in the tables are all good for sure.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: if it returns internal error you need to submit the job id to the public issue tracker  https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: Are you sure you've got standard SQL enabled?

Comment: 1. Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Comment: 2. I already submitted to issue tracker.

Comment: 3. Yes, pretty sure the standard sql is on

Comment: Have you created an issue tracker regarding your issue? Did it get any resolution yet? Make sure that you provide some sample Job IDs of the queries that are failing, which will be helpful for troubleshooting purposes.